# Distribution Certificate Deleted

Tags: ios, iphone

I have deleted the distribution certificate accidentally.I have created a new distribution certificate from developer portal. Does it affect my updated version of this app?

Answer (score 0):

It should not affect already uploaded builds. You will need the new, valid certificate to distribute new builds from now on.

Answer (score 0):

No, It will not affect your existing app on App Store.
But from now onwards you will have to distribute your apps using this certificate.
Also if you have other team members working with the same iTunes Account. You should distribute this certificate along with the private key with them also.